# How to hide object attribute in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have a class User, which has two attributes: `firstName` and `lastName`. I would like to know, if it is possible to return the User object from the database, hiding the `lastName` property.

Comment: What do you mean with "to hide"? what result do you what to accomplish? What does it mean "return the User object from the database?" What's the code you use to read a User entity? The question is not clear.

Comment: If you are trying to hide the result in an API, maybe you have to consider using DTOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose two ways to hide the object attribute,

the first one in query:

```
String query = "SELECT u.firstname FROM User u WHERE ...";
        return entityManager.createQuery(query, String.class).getSingleResult();
```

you just get the firstname attribute.

the second way, you get all the user object but you set the lastname to "";

```
public User findUser(){
    String query = "FROM User u WHERE ...";
            return entityManager.createQuery(query, User.class).getSingleResult();
}
```

after call of findUser()

```
User user = userService.findUser();
user.setLastName("");
```

This is an example with entitymanager, but the same you can do with session factory.